# My sql update query to update string json data

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with MySQL update.
I have one user table.
column name is id,name,user_condition
In my user_condition column. I have following data which is stored as string in Database.

```
{"2":"3.00","3":"4.00","6":"5.00","9":"6.00","12":"6.00"},
{"2":"3.7","3":"4.2","6":"5.00","9":"6.00","12":"6.00"} ,
.....
```

In the above string if one value is changed in the following way.
Here if user changed value of "2:3.00" to "2:3.5" 
Now I want to update those rows data whose value is less than "2:3.00"
What is the best possible way to update this record because I have thousand of record like that?

Comment: Which language you are using tag it? and you have tried something yet or not?

Comment: I am using PHP here.Language doesnot matter here.

Comment: Yes it matters because you have to fetch data first and update it.

Comment: I'd say the best way is to not collapse multiple values into the same field in the first place.

Comment: Yes that is the way I know but I want to do without fetching data.Direct executing update query.